# Running r script automatically when computer asleep (Mac)

Tags: r, macos, automation

I was wondering if there is an option to automate an R script to run every day, even when the computer is asleep?
I have a script which essentially downloads and saves some information from the web, and I want it to work everyday, even when I'm away from the computer. I've tried to use iCal and and crontab in terminal, but both seem to only work when I'm actively using the computer. Is there a way to schedule a script to run regardless?

Comment: [Code does not run when a mac is asleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365663/will-my-code-keep-running-when-mac-is-in-sleep-mode). You would need to [schedule your computer to wake up](https://superuser.com/questions/14836/crontab-to-wake-osx-from-sleep) and then use another process to launch your script. Any techniques you use would not be specific to R really.

Comment: that makes sense I guess. But I have a password, so if I schedule it to wake up (in system preferences), it will probably not work right?